# Large set of x,y coordinates. Efficient way to find any within certain distance of each other?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a large set of data points in a pandas dataframe, with columns containing x/y coordinates for these points. I would like to identify all points that are within a certain distance "d" of any other point in the dataframe.

I first tried to do this using 'for' loops, checking the distance between the first point and all other points, then the distance between the second point and all others, etc. Clearly this is not very efficient for a large data set.

Recent searching online suggests that the best way might be to use scipy.spatial.ckdtree, but I can't figure out how to implement this. Most examples I see check against a single x/y location, whereas I want to check all vs all. Is anyone able to provide suggestions or examples, starting from an array of x/y coordinates taken from my dataframe as follows:

```
points = df_sub.loc[:,['FRONT_X','FRONT_Y']].values
```

That looks something like this:

```
[[19091199.587  -544406.722]
 [19091161.475  -544452.426]
 [19091163.893  -544464.899]
 ...
 [19089150.04   -544747.196]
 [19089774.213  -544729.005]
 [19089690.516  -545165.489]]
```

The ideal output would be the ID's of all pairs of points that are within a cutoff distance "d" of each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Find all nearest neighbors within a specific distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424604/find-all-nearest-neighbors-within-a-specific-distance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`scipy.spatial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.html) has many good functions for handling distance computations.

Let's create an array `pos` of 1000 (x, y) points, similar to what you have in your dataframe.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

num = 1000
pos = np.random.uniform(size=(num, 2))

# Distance threshold
d = 0.25
```

From here we shall use the [`distance_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html) function to calculate pairwise distances. Then we use `np.argwhere` to find the indices of all the pairwise distances less than some threshold `d`.

```py
pair_dist = distance_matrix(pos, pos)

ids = np.argwhere(pair_dist < d)
```

`ids` now contains the "ID's of all pairs of points that are within a cutoff distance "d" of each other", as you desired.

### Shortcomings

Of course, this method has the shortcoming that we always compute the distance between each point and itself (returning a distance of `0`), which will always be less than our threshold `d`. However, we can exclude self-comparisons from our `ids` with the following fudge:

```py
pair_dist[np.r_[:num], np.r_[:num]] = np.inf
ids = np.argwhere(pair_dist < d)
```

Another shortcoming is that we compute the full symmetric pairwise distance matrix when we only really need the upper or lower triangular pairwise distance matrix. However, unless this computation really is a bottleneck in your code, I wouldn't worry too much about this.